# Leaflet plugins not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, leaflet, browserify

I'm trying to design a web app for mapping accessibility on my university. Unfortunately the map only loads until I try resize the map so they would shown on the whole webpage. Most of the plugins I tried to add (like Fullscreenmode or Location doesn't work, too). The page turns white. What did I do wrong?

Here are my snippets:

```js
// Initialize leaflet.js
var L = require('leaflet');

//OSM tiles attribution and URL
var osmLink = '<a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>';
var osmURL = 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
var osmAttrib = '&copy; ' + osmLink;

//Stamen Toner tiles attribution and URL
var stamenURL = 'http://stamen-tiles-{s}.a.ssl.fastly.net/toner/{z}/{x}/{y}.{ext}';
var stamenAttrib = 'Map tiles by <a href="http://stamen.com">Stamen Design</a>, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0">CC BY 3.0</a> &mdash; Map data &copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>';

//Creation of map tiles
var osmMap = L.tileLayer(osmURL, {
  attribution: osmAttrib
});
var stamenMap = L.tileLayer(stamenURL, {
  attribution: stamenAttrib,
  subdomains: 'abcd',
  ext: 'png'
});

//Map creation
var map = L.map('map', {
  zoomControl: false,
  layers: [osmMap]
}).setView([50.927, 6.931], 16);

//Base layers definition and addition
var baseLayers = {
  "OSM Mapnik": osmMap,
  "Stamen Toner": stamenMap
};



//Add baseLayers to map as control layers
L.control.layers(baseLayers).addTo(map);

//Fullscreen button
map.addControl(new L.Control.Fullscreen());

map.on('fullscreenchange', function() {
  if (map.isFullscreen()) {
    console.log('entered fullscreen');
  } else {
    console.log('exited fullscreen');
  }
});

map.isFullscreen() // Is the map fullscreen?
map.toggleFullscreen() // Either go fullscreen, or cancel the existing fullscreen.

// `fullscreenchange` Event that's fired when entering or exiting fullscreen.
map.on('fullscreenchange', function() {
  if (map.isFullscreen()) {
    console.log('entered fullscreen');
  } else {
    console.log('exited fullscreen');
  }
});

//create custom zoom Control on right bottom
var zoomControl = L.control.zoom(
  zoomOptions = {
    position: 'bottomright'
  }
).addTo(map);

// Initialize the base layer
//offer alternative base layer; include base layer choice toggle on top right of mapbox
var osm_mapnik = L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/jlambre1/cjtzjn4xv1ceo1fph8wuq1y9u/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoianVzbGFtYnJlIiwiYSI6ImNqeTB1ZGo4eTAxdXUzbmsyOG1xcmQ1NWMifQ.IWZKtDwcnUCq03fo9-ualg', {
  maxZoom: 19,
  attribution: '&copy; OSM Mapnik <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
}).addTo(map);
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Mapping Acces @UzK</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">


  <!-- Leaflet CDN-->
  <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/leaflet/0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
  <!-- Leaflet CSS-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">

  <!-- Custom Stylesheet -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles/main.css">

  <!-- Leaflet Fullscreen-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./leaflet-fullscreen/Control.FullScreen.css" />
  <script src="./leaflet-fullscreen/Control.FullScreen.js"></script>


  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!--Locate-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet.locatecontrol@[VERSION]/dist/L.Control.Locate.min.css" />

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet.locatecontrol@[VERSION]/dist/L.Control.Locate.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

  <!-- jQuery CDN-->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!--Switching Basemaps-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="L.Control.Basemaps.css" />
  <script src="L.Control.Basemaps-min.js"></script>

  <!-- Fullscreen -->
  <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-fullscreen/v1.0.1/Leaflet.fullscreen.min.js'></script>
  <link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-fullscreen/v1.0.1/leaflet.fullscreen.css' rel='stylesheet' />
</head>

And I receive this error message: https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-fullscreen/v1.0.1/leaflet.fullscreen.css' rel='stylesheet' />
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! `var L = require('leaflet')` looks suspicious from the very start...

Comment: This is because of nodejs, beefy and browserfiy....

Comment: The HTML code you show is not consistent with any of these at all.